# Creating an array with Indirect()

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to match an email address to a list on a different sheet. Here is the formula:

```
=IF(MATCH(B11,INDIRECT("'"&$D$1&"'!$a$1:$a$1000",1),0)=1,"No","Yes")
```

My problem is that Indirect only looks at the first value A1 and not the rest of the column.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're only checking if your `MATCH` returns `1`, i.e. if it's in the first position. But what you actually want to check is not if `MATCH(...)=1` but rather if is `#N/A` or not, so `ISNA` makes more sense.

Try this instead:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B11,INDIRECT("'"&$D$1&"'!$A:$A"),0)),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I copied it verbatim and it is returning "Yes" whet that in not the case. What should I look for?

Comment: update, I removed the ISNA and my results or "no" which are correct and "n/A" which I would like to be "Yes". thoughts?

Comment: @Daryn Perhaps `=IF(ISNUMBER([match]),"Yes","No")`

Comment: You probably need to swap the yes/no `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B11,INDIRECT("'"&$D$1&"'!$A:$A"),0)),"Yes","No")`

Comment: Do you need it returning the index value for found and "Yes" for not found? Try `IFERROR()` then.

Comment: @ValonMiller no, I'm pretty sure they are in the right order. `"No"` if the email address is not in the referenced column, `"Yes"` otherwise

Comment: @Daryn "... it is returning "Yes" whet that in not the case..."? when what is not the case? You want "Yes" when the value in cell B11 is in column A of the sheet whose name is in D1 right?

Comment: @Dan in his comment above he indicates that "no" is the positive case, i.e. when it is found, and "Yes" is the negative case, i.e. it is not found. Maybe the column is "Is email missing?" --  *update, I removed the ISNA and my results or "no" which are correct and "n/A" which I would like to be "Yes". thoughts? – Daryn*

Comment: @newacc2240 I do not need to return an index value.I simply want yes or no

Comment: Dan is correct, they are in the proper order. @Dan The responses are counter intuitive. Valon Miller is correct where no means the email adress WAS found in the match. Yes means that the email address WAS NOT found. Thank you all for the discussion. I appreciate your time

Comment: @Daryn so has swapping the yes and no answered the question then?

Comment: @Dan: I need to use (not(isna)) otherwise your solution is perfect.

Comment: @Daryn no don't do that, just switch the last two arguments of the `IF` statement. See my edit. And if it works, please accept the answer.

Comment: This is the solution I was able to find with @Dan's help: =IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(B11,INDIRECT("'"&$D$1&"'!$A:$A"),0))),"No","Yes")

Comment: @Daryn that is identical to `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(B11,INDIRECT("'"&$D$1&"'!$A:$A"),0)),"Yes","No")`

Comment: @Dan. You probabaly know more than I do but I don't want Yes returned if true. I want No returned if true. I believe your ISNA is correct but the match is would not be.

Comment: `=IF(ISNA(...),A,B)` is identical to `=IF(NOT(ISNA(...),B,A)`. You haven't changed any part of the `MATCH` clause...

Comment: All i know is, I need the Not to be there with "yes", "No". If I change that. It does not work. I don't know what else to say

Comment: Did you actually try switch the Yes and No arguments? In your you have No first, I'm saying instead of NOT put the Yes first. You can leave the NOT in, but your formula will just become longer thus harder to read and also (minutely) less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

`MATCH` returns the index of the first match, as an integer. Your `IF()` condition is only ever true if the value is matched in `A1`.

Try something like this:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,INDIRECT("'"&$D$1&"'!$A$1:$A$1000",1),0)),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Hi Valon. Thank you for your help. The formula is working as expected with the first answer.